# Energy Method for Regularizing Effect of Heat Equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, calculus-of-variations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am trying to show the following:
Let u solve the homogeneous heat equation in the cylinder $\Omega$ x $(0, \infty)$ with vanishing dirichlet data and initial condition g.  Multiple the PDE by $tu_t$ and apply the energy method to show that $\int_{\Omega}| \nabla u(x,t)|^2dx < \frac{1}{t}\int_{\Omega}|g(x)|^2dx$.

I'm not sure how I apply the energy method once I have multiplied the PDE through by $tu_t$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

One dimensional Heat equation ($\nabla u=u_x$)

$$u_t = \Delta u=cu_{xx}$$

Energy method, define 
$$E(t)=\int_{\Omega} u^2 dx $$

Due to vanishing dirichlet BC  you get
$$E'(t)=\int_{\Omega} 2 u u_t dx =\int_{\Omega} 2 u c u_{xx} dx =
2c u u_x\Big|_{\partial\Omega}-2c\int_{\Omega} u_x^2 dx =-2c\int_{\Omega} u_x^2 dx =\quad
-2c\int_{\Omega}\|\nabla u\|^2 dx \le0
$$
You have also to explain here why you allowed to differentiate under the integral.

Since $E'\le0$, $E$ is decreasing and, together with
$$E(0)=\int_{\Omega} g^2 dx $$
we got
$$E(t)\le \int_{\Omega} g^2 dx, \quad \forall t\ge0$$

So you got
$$\int_{\Omega}\|\nabla u\|^2 dx= -\frac{1}{2c}E'(t)=\frac{1}{2c}\left|E'(t)\right|$$

I'm actually fail to see why it should be 
$< \frac{1}{t}\int_{\Omega}|g(x)|^2dx$

Comment: I have seen this argument used before for energy method problems, but at what step does multiplying the pde by $tu_t$ come in to play and how does that affect the energy functional?  I guess that's where I'm confused the most.

Comment: So you can show $E'(t) \leq 0$, implying $E(T) \leq E(0)$, which shows that $\int_{\Omega} u^2 dx \leq \int_{\Omega} g^2 dx$, which is not the conclusion I am trying to draw...

Comment: see the update\edit. are you sure you solving correct problem?

Comment: The hint in the problem suggests multiplying the PDE through by $tu_t$ and then apply the energy method.  I've tried playing around with it, but as long as $E(t)=\int_{\Omega} u^2 dx$ you still make the same substitution that $u_t = \Delta u$ in the energy method process since multiplying through by $tu_t$ doesn't change that....

Comment: exactly! where the question comes from?

Comment: It's not from a formal text as far as I know.  Maybe I have to select a different E(t) functional.

Comment: If this is your homework or so - talk to your professor and make sure you do not spending time for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure how to use the hint, but here are two possible solutions (compared with Michael Medvinky's post, I take $c=1$).

1) *Spectral method*: Let
$$
-\Delta=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lambda_k \langle\phi_k,\cdot\rangle\phi_k
$$
be the spectral decomposition of the Laplacian with Dirichlet boundary conditions. The solution of the heat equation is given by 
$$
u(t,x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-t\lambda_k}\langle \phi_k,g\rangle\phi_k(x).
$$
Thus
$$
\int_\Omega \lvert \nabla u(t,x)\rvert^2\,dx=-\int_\Omega u(t,x)\Delta u(t,x)\,dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda_k e^{-2t\lambda_k}\lvert \langle\phi_k,g\rangle\rvert^2.
$$
Since $\lambda e^{-2t\lambda}\leq (2et)^{-1}$ for $\lambda\geq 0$, we have
$$
\int_\Omega \nabla u(t,x)\rvert^2\,dx\leq \frac{1}{2et}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lvert\langle\phi_k,g\rangle\rvert^2=\frac{1}{2et}\int_\Omega g(x)^2\,dx.
$$
If $g\neq 0$, we get the strict inequality claimed in the question (of course it's simply not true for $g=0$).

2) *Energy method*: Let 
$$E(t)=\frac 1 2\int_\Omega u(t,x)^2\,dx.$$
As shown in Michael Medvinky's post, the derivative of $E$ is given by
$$
E'(t)=-\int_\Omega \lvert \nabla u(t,x)\rvert^2\,dx.
$$
The second derivative of $E$ is
$$
E''(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\int_\Omega u(t,x)\Delta u(t,x)\,dx=\int_\Omega (\Delta u(t,x))^2+u(t,x)\Delta^2 u(t,x)\,dx=2\int_\Omega (\Delta u(t,x))^2\,dx\geq 0.
$$
Hence $E'(t)$ is increasing and we get
$$
\frac1  2\int_\Omega g(x)^2\,dx=E(0)=E(t)-\int_0^t E'(s)\,ds\geq E(t)-t E'(t)\geq -tE'(t)=t\int_\Omega\lvert \nabla u(t,x)\rvert^2\,dx.
$$
Again, you get the desired strict inequality from the question unless $g=0$.